# Multi tenancy website hosting for legacy monolith web app in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, hosting, azure-webapps

We had a legacy monolith website application that is hosted on Azure windows server and had 10 customers using it, now as the application data grows the bandwidth of the application is affecting each customer because they were hosted in single server as a single website. Now the client wants to split the database as per customer separately to reduce the database load, so we divided the databases as per customer.
Regarding the website, we still had a dilemma on how to proceed, so we already divide the databases so we are thinking as

1. it is better to host each customer website on separate servers?
2. create a different website on a single server for each and every customer?.

Because the clients want this to be scalable and  100%, that one client’s activities and usage will not affect another, as well as be able to easily distinguish cost.

The client also asked to differentiate how much cost occurring for each customer on the resource groups,
previously we had a shared resource group.

Could anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement fits you could leverage [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview) WebApps (PAAS solution).

You can host apps in the same App Service Plan or isolate your app into new App Service plan (as per your requirement) by having tradeoff between level-of control and costs.

Or to have greater control on the underlying VMs you could leverage Azure VMs (IAAS solution).

To start with, kindly take a look at this approach - [Common web application architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#monolithic-applications-and-containers) – monolithic application design using Azure App Service.

You could create the web application as separate App Service apps. This design lets you run them in separate App Service plans so they can be scaled independently. If you don't need that level of scalability initially, you can deploy the apps into the same plan and move them into separate plans later if necessary.

The pricing tier of an App Service plan determines what App Service features you get and how much you pay for the plan.

[Azure App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans)

[App Service plans pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/app-service/plans/)

Azure offers a number of ways to host your application code.

Kindly checkout this [architecture guide on compute decision choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree)

Resource Group is a just a container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. The resource group can include all the resources for the solution, or only those resources that you want to manage as a group. It doesn't have direct cost implications, but the resources/services (in this case App Service) under it does.

You may wish to know:

[Explore and analyze costs with cost analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/quick-acm-cost-analysis)

[Prevent unexpected charges with Azure billing and cost management](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/getting-started)